# How to avoid backslashes in GSON JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Java POJO

```
public class TagBean {
  private String type;
  private String id;

  public TagBean(String type, String id) {
    this.type = type;
    this.id = id;       
  }
    // getters
    // setters   
}
```

I'm building pojo's and adding them to a List, as

```
....
List<TagBean> channelsList = new ArrayList<>();
List<TagBean> showsList = new ArrayList<>();
for each <business logic> {
   if value=channels {
      channelsList.add(new TagBean(...));
   }
   if value=shows {
      showsList.add(new TagBean(...));
   }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonObject tjsonObject = new JsonObject();
tjsonObject.addProperty("channels", gson.toJson(channelsList));
tjsonObject.addProperty("shows", gson.toJson(showsList));

JsonObject mainjsonObject = mainjsonObject.add("tags", tjsonObject);

return mainjsonObject;
```

My output is:

```
{
"tags": {
    "channels": "[{\"type\":\"channel\",\"id\":\"channel\",\"name\":\"Channel\",\"parent\":\"SXM\"}]",
    "shows": "[{\"type\":\"shows\",\"id\":\"shows\",\"name\":\"Shows\",\"parent\":\"SXM\"},{\"type\":\"shows\",\"id\":\"howard\",\"name\":\"Howard Stern\",\"parent\":\"shows\"},{\"type\":\"shows\",\"id\":\"howardstern\",\"name\":\"Howard Stern\",\"parent\":\"howard\"}]",
    "sports": "[]"
}
}
```

How can i remove the backslashes? So the output is like:

```
{
  "tags": {
     "channels": " [{"type":"channel","id":"channel","name":"Channel","parent":"SXM"}]",
    "shows": "[{"type":"shows","id":"shows","name":"Shows","parent":"SXM"},{"type":"shows","id":"howard","name":"Howard Stern","parent":"shows"}....
```

There were few other posts, but none explained this.

Comment: backslashes are meant to escape double quotes. that should not be a problem for parsing or printing values. Where are you putting the outputs?

Comment: Yes,that is not a problem if we can use "fromJson()".. but we wanted to use this in a spreadsheet and process it further. This doesn't look standard json output with backslashes in front on double quotes? Is this is a limitation in GSON library?

Comment: You do want nested double quotes without escaping, And how do you think that is a standard json? Are you sure you will be able to parse them back without escaping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by this:

```
tjsonObject.addProperty("channels", gson.toJson(channelsList));
```

What that is doing is converting `channelsList` to a string containing a representation of the list in JSON, then setting the property to that string.  Since the string contains JSON meta-characters, they **must** be escaped when the strings are serialized ... a second time.

*I think* that you need to do this instead:

```
tjsonObject.add("channels", gson.toJsonTree(channelsList));
```

That should produce this:

```
{
  "tags": {
     "channels":     
        [{"type":"channel","id":"channel","name":"Channel","parent":"SXM"}],
     "shows": 
        [{"type":"shows","id":"shows","name":"Shows","parent":"SXM"},
         {"type":"shows","id":"howard","name":"Howard Stern","parent":"shows"}
   ....
```

That is slightly different to what your question asked for, but it has the advantage of being syntactically valid JSON!

Comment: Thanks @stephen-c using toJsonTree did resolve the issue. The change i did was                         
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonObject tjsonObject = new JsonObject();
tjsonObject.add("channels", gson.toJsonTree(channelsList));
tjsonObject.add("shows", gson.toJsonTree(showsList));

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C you saved my day with this hell of extra ddback slashes. Doc says using toJsonTree: "This method should be used when the specified object is not a generic type"

Answer (score 2):

```
    String mainJsonStr = mainjsonObject.toString();
    mainJsonStr = mainJsonStr.replace("\\\\", ""); //replace the \
    System.out.println(mainJsonStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `gson.toJson` returns a String, and

`tjsonObject.addProperty("channels", gson.toJson(channelsList));`

this will add channels as a string and not as a JSON object.
One possible solution is to convert the string returned from `gson.toJson` to JSON object first then add it to the parent JSON object like

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonObject tjsonObject = new JsonObject();
tjsonObject.put("channels", new JsonObject(gson.toJson(channelsList)));
tjsonObject.put("shows", new JsonObject(gson.toJson(showsList)));
```

this will treat channels and shows as JSON object

Answer (score 0):

All **strings** in java have to escape quotes in them. So jsonInString should have slashes in it. When you output jsonInString though it shouldn't have the quotes. Are you looking at it in a **debugger** or something?

**Just parse json directly and check** - **will get the output**

Answer (score -1):

above solution is not working anymore since GSON 2.8.*
use gson.toJsonTree(jsonText).getAsString(); instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).